# Specifying CanCan limitation based on an association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, cancan

My `User` model has the following action:

```
  def release(idea)
    if idea.status == "claimed"
      idea.status = "available"
      self.ideas.delete(idea)
    end
  end
```

Each `user` `has_many` ideas, and this is the way to release an idea and say "I don't want to be responsible for this idea anymore."

However, the current implementation lets one user `release` an idea owned by another user. I could easily solve this in the function itself by checking for `idea.user_id` but I'm trying to learn how to use CanCan and rolify... which is where the problem starts.

`ability.rb` says:

```
if user.has_role? :user
  can :release, Idea, user_id: user.id
end
```

This fails in rspec:

```
Failures:

  1) User manipulates ideas: can't change an idea he doesn't own
     Failure/Error: let(:james) {create(:user)}
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `find_or_create_by' for #<Rolify::Adapter::ResourceAdapter:0xabc7d98>
```

**tl;dr:** Should I be specifying abilities for `User` or for `Idea`? If `User`, how should I word the condition?

Thank you!

**Edit: User factory:**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    name Faker::Name.name
    email Faker::Internet.email
    provider "MyString"
    uid {"user_#{rand(1000).to_s}" }

    trait :admin do
      after(:create) {|user| user.add_role(:admin)}
    end

    trait :guest do
      after(:create) {|user| user.add_role(:guest)}
    end

    trait :authorized_user do
      after(:create) do |user|
        user.add_role(:user)
        user.remove_role(:guest)
      end
    end

  end
end
```

Comment: Your cancan code looks okay to me at first glance. This looks more like an issue with your User factory to me. Might be worth posting relevant portions of your spec, model and factory code.

Comment: The answer to the tl;dr is, spec abilities for Idea, _mock_ the Idea when speccing the User (if possible).

Comment: @PaulRussell - I've since changed the spec (have had to refactor not to use CanCan), but I posted the factory above. Any insights? Currently I'm stuck and unable to use CanCan in my app...

Comment: @iain - I think maybe I picked the wrong word; didn't mean "specify" as in an spec (for testing), but rather "set". Thanks for taking a look at the question!

Comment: @ezuk Hmm. Again, can't see anything obviously wrong with that factory. Have you got a detailed stack trace for the NoMethodError? I'm wondering what's even calling `find_or_create_by`...